# Sorting a dynamically filled array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that is initialized like such `var generationObject = [{string:"", score: 0}];`

which I then fill dynamically:

```
for(var i = 0; i < amount_offspring; i++)
{
    // "load" text into array and send the string to see if it evolves
    generationObject[i].string = evolve(start_text, characters, mutation_rate);
    // then score the string
    generationObject[i].score = score(target_text, generationObject.string);
}
```

I then want to sort this array by score. I don't know what's best, to sort it in the `for` loop or sort the entire array afterwards.

I will then take the string of the highest scoring object and pass it through the function again, recursively.

So what would be a good way to go about this sort function? I've seen some here use this

```
generationObject.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.score) - (b.score);
});
```

But I'm not sure if `.sort` is still supported? This didnt seem to work for me though.

Comment: If course sort of supported. Instead of circling around the problem, show the relevant code and ask a specific question

Comment: [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is supported across all major browsers.

Comment: @Thriggle You are correct, was just editing my comment when I noticed yours. Whoops! Getting my languages mixed up. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @FelixRosén, Look at [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#expanded-example) on sorting an array of objects. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

generationObject is an array, not an object, so `score(target_text, generationObject.string);` could be the problem, as .string will be undefined. (Did you mean `generationObject[i].string`?)
Try building your array like this:

```
var generationObject = []
for(var i = 0; i < amount_offspring; i++)
{
    evolved_string = evolve(start_text, characters, mutation_rate)
    generationObject.push({
       string: evolved_string,
       score: score(target_text, evolved_string)
    })
}
```

And then Array.prototype.sort should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Dont you have to do, though `generationObject[i].push({..` ?

Comment: Nope! You start with an empty array, and build it iteratively using `.push`, which appends to the array. You want `generationObject[i]` to be an object of the form `{string:"<some string>", score: <some number>}`, but it will be undefined until you fill the array.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your sorting logic outside the `for` loop, since if you put it inside, the object array will be sorted `N` times, where `N` being the iterations of your loop. The following are two ways to do it-

1. **By using [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function-** To clarify your question, `sort()` is still supported across almost all the browsers. If you are still concerned about the browser compatibility, you can check the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to see the list of supported browsers.

   ```
   generationObject = generationObject.sort(function(a, b) {
       return parseInt(a.score) - parseInt(b.score);
   });
   ```
2. **By using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/)-**
   In underscore, you can take advantage of the [sortBy()](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) function.

> Returns a (stably) sorted copy of list, ranked in ascending order by the results of running each value through iteratee. iteratee may also be the string name of the property to sort by (eg. length).

You can simply do this in underscorejs-

```
    generationObject = _.sortBy(generationObj, 'score');
```